# This pyramid must be centuries and thousands, even, of years old

Tags: listening

Here's a subtitle of the TV drama "Sesame Street: Bert and Ernie in a Pyramid".

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=8yiqGtZXCmQ

0:22

> Burt: Yeah, look at the knowledge here.
>   This pyramid must be centuries and thousands, even, of years old.
>   This is great.

Perhaps Burt wants to say "This pyramid must almost be centuries and thousands, even, of years old."
But it seems to me that he says "is" instead of "must".
What exactly does he say?

Comment: "This pyramid is… oh, must be…" The whole sentence is fumbled, made to sound like he's guessing & making it up as he goes.

Comment: But be advised that "centuries of years old" is not grammatical.  "Hundreds of years old" would be gramamtical, as would "centuries old". "Thousands of years old" is grammatical but "millenia of years old" would be ungrammatical.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> "Sesame Street: Bert and Ernie in a Pyramid".
>
> Video Clip: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=8yiqGtZXCmQ (0:22)

I hear Bert say the following:

- *"This pyramid is...ahh must be centuries...and **thousands even** of years old, this is great!"*

The "ahh" is typically written as [hmm](https://www.google.com/search?q=definition+hmm) or [um](https://www.google.com/search?q=um+definition) and is considered to be a [filler word](https://www.google.com/search?q=filler+words+linguistics).

To illustrate meaning, it could be written as follows:

This pyramid is... hmm... This pyramid must be centuries (and thousands even!) of years old; this is great!